# Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation

Tags: office-365, search-results, central-administration, refinement-panel, site-settings

**Hi, 
When I try to add a mapping to RefinableString00[image], it tells me: "The settings could not be saved because of an internal error: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation." I am working on SharePoint online..
how to fix this please ?**

Comment: this usually means you dont have the correct permissions - can you try it on tenant level?

Comment: I've had an error while trying to updated the search schema before as well.  Cannot recall if this is the same error, but I found that by going the opposite way (mapping a managed property to a crawled property instead of a crawled property to a managed property), it worked.  I also recall that it started working again some time later (a day or two later).

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same error a few days ago.
Reported it to MS Support and they told me there might be a bug in SharepointOnline which causes the Managed Properties page to default to the incorrect level of site instead of sitecol

So avoid using this URL

```
_layouts/15/managedproperty.aspx?property=RefinableString00&level=site
```

And simply use this URL instead

```
_layouts/15/managedproperty.aspx?property=RefinableString00&level=sitecol
```

Comment: Worked for me, thansk!

Answer (score -1):

I've seen this error several times when I tried to adjust a managed property on the site collection level, you should try it in the

SharePoint Admin Centre > Search > Schema.

Worked for me.